# How to Call 3rd party API using Azure function and display in SharePoint online Site using SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx-webparts, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-functions

I have create one azure function to call 3rd party API and used application ID in SPFx webpart but when on 'gulp serve' it shows error.
I have tried in both team site as well as developer site.
I am working on Office 365 Enterprise E3 trial.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the 'Developer Preview' site feature enabled? This is what needs to be enabled to use these experimental features.

You can turn this on by going to Admin Centres -> Sharepoint -> Settings -> Enable Preview Features.
[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/enable-or-disable-preview-features)

Comment: Preview feature inside Admin Center is already enabled.I cannot find developer preview in site feature.

Comment: How about Admin Center > Settings > Organisation Profile > Release Preferences? If release preferences isn't set to 'Targeted Release' then sometimes experimental features don't deploy to your tenancy.

This can take an hour or two to deploy also.

Comment: Ohk I have done that change.Let's wait for and check whether issue resolves or not.