# Problem making 3rd party react API POST calls using SPFx

Tags: react, api, cors, post

I am having same issue as posted this in post [How to Call 3rd party API using Azure function and display in SharePoint online Site using SPFx?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/247106/how-to-call-3rd-party-api-using-azure-function-and-display-in-sharepoint-online). Did any one find a solution?

Here is the sample code:

```
axios
     .post('https://api.awardco.com/api/report-api',{
      reportName: 'Recognition Details',
      returnType: 'JSON',
      startDate: '09/1/2023',
      endDate: '09/18/2023'
      }, {headers: {
        'content-type': 'text/json',
        'apikey':'APIKEY',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*Origin*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Authorization',
        'Origin': '*Origin*',
      }
    })
     .then(res=>{
      const awards = res.data;
      this.setState({awards});
      console.log(this.state.awards)
     }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```